# Can I disable the update notification of VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, auto-update

VsCode nags me everytime there's an update, i.e. every month or so.

Installing the update is a bit complicated (go to Website, download Deb, open terminal, sudo dpkg etc.) so I would like VsCode to not bother me with this update bar.

Is it possible?

I couldn't find a setting that allows to hide this bar..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add this to `settings.json`:

```js
"update.mode": "none",
```

Comment: Looks like it, thanks!

Comment: FYI - `update.channel` has been deprecated. Instead, use `update.mode": "none"`

Comment: I can confirm, thanks. It's also available in Settings if you search for "update".